# Connect a local repository with a remote repository

Tags: git, repository

I have a local repository. I created the whole application, but now I want to push it to a remote repository. I already have remote repo as well. How can I connect these two repositories without losing any work that I did?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Use:

```
git remote add origin <remote_repo_URL>
git push --all origin
```

If you want to set all of your branches to automatically use this remote repository when you use `git pull`, add `--set-upstream` to the push:

```
git push --all --set-upstream origin
```

Comment: remote repo url should something like this? `https://example.com/projects/luotsi/repositories/git/marketing-site-redux`

Comment: Probably, yes.  It usually ends with something like `https://example.com/.../reponame.git`, although the `.git` ending is not technically required.

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to try it and see.  Git will let you know if it's not right.

Comment: I did it it give me this error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Is your app in a local repository yet (i.e. have you at some point done `git init` and made commits and stuff)? That error message means you're not in a repository.

Comment: go one folder level down, your repo is in another castle

Answer (score 2):

A one line exact answer is [provided by *vergenzt*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188801/connect-a-local-repository-with-a-remote-repository/11188828#11188828), but if you want to go through the details on how to commit your code and connect a local and remote GitHub repository and push code into the remote repository using Git CLI, you can go through this article:
*[Beginners guide to Git using CLI](https://medium.com/geekstrends/a-beginners-guide-to-starting-with-git-cli-1d5c44af0a4)*

Comment: *You* allegedly wrote the referenced Medium article. Why is "GitHub" misspelt as "Github" in the first half, but not in the second half?

Answer (score 1):

First make this command:

```
git remote add origin {URL for the remote repository}
```

Then tab this command:

```
git push origin master
```

Note the name of master is the name of the remote repository on GitHub. If it has another name, like *main* or something else, make it *main* instead of *master*.

It's expected to connect and push your local repo now. If something happens or any error appear, try this command:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have

- your local project already tracked by git,
- an empty remote repository existing, which you want to contain the project,

do the following steps:

```
cd existingLocalRepo
git remote set-url origin <remote_repo_URL>
git push -u origin --all
```

Explanation:

1. navigate to your local repo
2. tell git where the remote repo is located
3. upload/push your local branches to the remote repo