# How can I clone a git program that I already have on my computer?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket project that I want to start working on. However, I already have the files because I took them on a USB. It's a fairly large project, and I don't want to have to download the full thing if I clone it.

Is there a way I can clone the project without downloading the files from the internet, then paste my files in the project folder and have them linked? I tried doing just that but starting having missing HEAD problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connect local repo with remote repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188801/connect-local-repo-with-remote-repo)

Comment: Is the `.git` directory included in the files you took on the USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just copy the entire directory, as long as the hidden `.git` directory comes with your project, you'll have all the git history, It'll be just like you cloned it again.