# Add existing local PyCharm Python project to an initiated but empty GitHub repository?

Tags: python, github, pycharm

I'm trying to follow the PyCharm instructions on linking a local Python PyCharm project with a GitHub repository. The instructions take the user through the steps necessary to create and initiate a GitHub repository from the comfort of PyCharm. It then goes into checking in your code etc.

Unfortunately, I've done things a little bit differently, causing a bit of a roadblock.

I created a GitHub repository online, adding the readme and license data. This puts me out of sync with the PyCharm instructions (that step could have been done within PyCharm). So, my question is, how do I synch a PyCharm project up with an existing but otherwise empty GitHub repository?

**Edit #1**
In response to some of the comments (thanks for your time and attention), I want to know how to do this *only* through PyCharm due to the mixed experience in my team. This work is for several users who aren't going to be computer-savvy. There is me (the software engineer/scientist) and several medical doctors. The med doctors will edit text files while I do the actual development. I'd rather they did everything through PyCharm for reasons of technical consistency (different machines, text encoding, you name it).

This is also why this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect a local repository with a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188801/connect-a-local-repository-with-a-remote-repository)

Comment: so you are saying you have changes on GitHub not present on your local (readme) and you have changes on your local not present on the remote (source) ?

Comment: I have a local project linked to a GitHub repository (using a generated security token). But I have already initiated the repository online; the PyCharm instructions only demonstrate how to start a GitHub repository by creating it from within PyCharm.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Thanks for the comment, but it's not quite the same. How is this done inside PyCharm, not Git via a terminal.

Comment: @AnthonyNash you can do it inside the terminal and PyCharm will pick it up. But you could also [Add a remote repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-remote) in Pycharm

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych again, many thanks for the information, it's appreciated. I've edited my question to explain why I can't do this through the terminal.

Comment: So does my [second suggestion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-remote) help?